# native javascript if clicked on html do something

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, native, removeclass

I'm trying to not depend of jquery by using native javascript.

The button does not work but the if statement which wants to express: if there is the class mobile-menu-open and somebody clicks or tabs on any part of the site I will see eureca on my console.

The intention is that if the user clicks anywhere else this class `mobile-menu-open` is removed.

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

    var mobileButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="mobile-menu"]')[0];

    mobileButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

        document.body.classList.toggle('mobile-menu-open');

        if( mobileButton.classList.contains('mobile-menu-open') && document.body.addEventListener('click') ){
            console.log('eureca');
        }

    });


})();
```

Somebody could help me with this?

Comment: Where and when is the code called? If it's not after the DOM has loaded, then your attempt to add a listener to your button won't work because the button doesn't exist. Also, adding the listener in your `if` statement is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: Look at the `document` event `DOMContentLoaded` for standards-compliant browsers, the `document` event `onreadystatechange` for older versions of IE, and the `window` event `onload` as a last resort.

Comment: @MattBurland This javascript is loaded at the end of the body tag. I want to create function that if the user clicks or tabs in any part of the document the class mobile-menu-open is removed. how could I do this?

Comment: @DissidentRage I checked your answer and thanks for it but I do not understand well what you mean. I'm used to use jquery but want to learn how to use native javascript, so this native JS is new for me. This project should only cover for IE9+. Could you do an asnwer with the code so I can see it more clearly and maybe understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want to support IE9+ this should do the trick:

```
function toggleClass(elem,cls) {
    var classes = elem.className.split(/\s+/);
    var search = classes.indexOf(cls);

    if(search >= 0) {
        classes.splice(search,1);
    } else {
        classes.push(cls);
    }

    elem.className = classes.join(' ');
}

function menuOpen() {
    var cls = 'mobile-menu-open';
    toggleClass(document.body,cls);

    if(document.body.className.split(/\s+/).indexOf(cls) >= 0) {
        console.log('menu open'); }
    }

function init() {
    var mobileButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-js="mobile-menu"]');

    if(mobileButtons.length>0) {
        mobileButtons[0].addEventListener('click',menuOpen,false);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init,false);
```

The other events I had you look at were in case you wanted to develop something that also supports antiquated versions of IE.

Note: If you value performance, `querySelectorAll` is [not particularly fast](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname) so you may have better results doing `getElementsByTagName('*')`  first (or a more specific tag name if possible) then looping through the resultant `nodeList`.

**Edit:** Instead of using `classList` I'm just using the `className` attribute and splitting it by whitespace to get an array of classes. It searches for the given class name in that array. If it finds it, it removes it by the index, and if it doesn't, it adds it. It then sets `className` to the array joined with spaces.

Comment: @Dissedent Rage thank you very much for the information! But, it still does not answer my question that if there is a click on the the html the mobile-menu-open class is not removed. As you said the code maybe changes if its for IE9+, I'm using the following links for native javascript: http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/63383858003/how-to-forget-about-jquery-and-start-using-native, http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ If you know more links that could share it with me please!

Comment: I made an edit. As for sources MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) seems to be all the rage, though personally I've learned by trying to do stuff and looking for ways to do things.